# Why is the actual Switch image/animation not shown?

Tags: java, android

I have a Switch declared in my XML which is a part of an Activity using a specific theme:

```xml
<Switch
      android:id="@+id/sw_TakeTime_SelectRange"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:switchPadding="@dimen/dim_ButtonPadding"
      android:showText="false"
      android:text="@string/sw_SelectDateRange_Switch_Range"
      android:textColor="@color/Mercedes_BLACK"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      android:theme="@style/SwitchCompatStyle"
      android:switchMinWidth="20dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_SelectDateRange_Confirm"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cv_SelectDateRange"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bt_SelectDateRange_Confirm"/>
```

but the switch animation is not shown...
This is the Preview:

[image]

This is the running application...

[image]

This is what I edited in `SwitchCompatStyle`

```xml
<style name="SwitchCompatStyle">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/Mercedes_RED</item>
  </style>
```

I figured out, that the real problem is the Theme of my Activity, which is set to

```xml
<activity android:name=".activity_SelectDateRange"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
```

This transparent theme includes:

```xml
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name = "android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
  </style>
```

If I use this in combination with the switch the animation is not working anymore.
I tried to delete setting by setting in the theme, to detect which one is the problem, but I can't figure it out. Maybe it is a combination of settings.

Answer (score 2):

This indeed seems to be a bug. I have the same problem. If I click on the Switch itself it animates fine but if I change the switch state while the NavigationDrawer is open there is no animation.

See this for the Android Issue Tracker entry: [SwitchCompat.setChecked does not animate inside RecyclerView](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196652)

Comment: I'm a beginner and this is why I always think it is my fault and not the fault of the system... probably there is a real bug, but I think I just did something wrong. The activity which contains my switch uses a translucent theme and I think this affects my switch, too. I edited my Question