# Switch button animation doesn't work in Drawer Navigation View

Tags: android, kotlin, switch-statement, material-design, navigation-drawer

After spending a lot of time and not finding a suitable solution, I decided to turn to this service for help.
I have an example of [the simplest application that implements Drawer](https://github.com/waseefakhtar/Navigation-Drawer). This example contains only menu items without any implementations. In the menu item **Share**, I added a **Switch** and a listener to it:

**main_nav.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat"
    android:title="@string/menu_share" />
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
  val menuItem = navigation_view.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_share)
  val switch_id = menuItem.actionView as SwitchCompat
  switch_id.isChecked = true
  switch_id.setOnClickListener {
   // TODO: empty scope
  }
```

The switch works smoothly and with animation as shown below:

[image]

But now I need to **turn off the Home menu item** if the **Switch is off**:

```
switch_id.setOnClickListener {
     navigation_view.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_home).isEnabled = switch_id.isChecked
}
```

After adding this line, **my Switch animation breaks**!

[image]

I spent two days solving this issue and in the end to no avail.

**My question:** WTF with android menu in 2021? Why does accessing a menu item break the animation and how can I fix it? I would be grateful for any help !!

Comment: Did you try using `setOnCheckedChangeListener` and using the provided boolean  instead of `setOnClickListener` ?

Example:

```switch_id.setOnCheckedChangedListener { _, isChecked ->
     navigation_view.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_home).isEnabled = isChecked
}
```

Comment: @Kilian thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this method doesn't work.

Comment: @Kilian Perhaps it has something to do with these answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57714721/4512868 and the issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37074309, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199561560) with this question in Android Tracker and got an answer:

> Either way, this is likely to be a non-trivial fix for an issue that
> is not a regression and not impacting correctness of the UI. At this
> time, we have no plans to address the issue.

And then a workaround was suggested:

> Something along the lines of adding a setOnCheckedChangeListener that
> posts a delayed Runnable to effect the change. I'd recommend asking on
> StackOverflow if you need a detailed example.
>
> E.g.
> [How to delay "runOnUiThread" in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62511220/how-to-delay-runonuithread-in-android)

I added a `postDelay(200)` and the Switch animation works fine:

```
switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
     Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
         navigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_home).isEnabled = isChecked
     }, 200)
}
```